# Voted Perceptron on Weka

Tags: weka, perceptron

I am trying to run the "Voted Perceptron" on iris data set using weka. However, when I load the data, the Voted Perceptron refuses to run, while it runs on many other data sets like ionosphere.arff, diabetes.arff etc.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Because VotedPerceptron only works on datasets that are binary classifiers. Iris.arff has three different classification types while diabetes.arff and ionosphere.arff only have two.

If you want it to work you'll have to entirely remove one of iris.arff's classification types.